# How to copy and rename multiple tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy and rename 100+ tables in a SQL Server database, retaining all their columns and data.

I am cloning a website and want to keep the database information all on the same database.

For example, say I have 100 tables that begin with the prefix "foo" and I want to create new tables with the prefix "anotherfoo" that contain all the same data.

How do can I do this in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: It makes about a million times more sense to go with a second database, why not go that route?

Comment: From your description you are in for a long battle. You will have to modify every single query everywhere to pull from the newly created tables. Use a second database. Then all you have to change to the connection string in your web.config and you are done.

Comment: The reason to keep it all in the same database is for cost.  It's a corporate site running on Azure, and they charge you for every tiny thing.

Comment: OK. You do realize that the likelihood of mistakes if pretty big right? You will have to change every single query in the entire site. I would avoid putting a "prefix" on the table name and instead use a different schema. The way to copy them with existing data is to use "select into"